# Django doesn't show stacktrace after Debug = True

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi

I'm running Django, with nginx+fcgi on production. I've changed DEBUG = True in settings.py (I have no users on my site, I just want to see a stacktrace for an error that randomly shows up on production).

I've done:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
[[Python]]
import settings
print settings.DEBUG
>>> True
```

Yet I keep getting 404 pages.

Comment: Did you restart nginx after you made the change? Why 404 btw.? You should load the page where it is supposed to show the 500!!!

Comment: I killed the python process, and restarted runfcgi. How do I restart nginx?

Comment: In Ubuntu I would do 'sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`. Though if you killed the python process and did reload the runfcgi it should be ok already. Still the question about the 404 pages. Shouldn't you get 500 pages when running into errors?

Comment: So I actually use the same template for 404 and for 500 pages, so I'm not sure anymore which ones they were. I checked the stacktrace that was supposed to be emailed to me, and it was an Internal Server Error.

Regardless, when I entered [domain].com/blahblah, I still received the 404 page.

Comment: Who's showing the 404/50x error page? Is it Django or Nginx? Maybe you have configured Nginx to do it so it gets covered... Can you pst your Nginx conf (sites-available/<my_site> file for instance)?

Comment: So turns out restarting the Rackspace cloud server made all the difference; all my changes kicked in. Thanks for all your help!